# Как создать строку из списка?

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.x, строки, списки

Есть список: `['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8',',','9']`
нужно создать строку: `'12345678,9'`

Answer (score 2):

```
f = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8',',','9']

print("".join(f))
```

Документация (англ.): [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Comment: Я сегодня узнал, что если вбить в Гугл: *python string methods*, то список методов показан прямо на странице с результатами, даже не обязательно на ссылку кликать. Стоит привести ссылку на документацию—на английском ([официальную](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)) и на русском, если знаете хороший ресурс

Comment: @jfs намекаете добавить источник?